# Response time statistic

Tags: java, performance, profiling, monitoring

I'm looking for production ready monitoring tool like https://github.com/alvins82/java-mini-profiler-core but with persisted statistic. Something lighter than AppDynamics but more than mini-profiler.

Comment: Have you taken a look at NewRelic?

Comment: @perception, yes, it's Saas, but i wan't to use it inside private company applications